# How to write multiple transformation of the same column in one function?

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have a dataframe:

```
ID       value
1      he following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’
2      Attaching package: ‘magrittr’
3      package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2
4      Warning messages:
```

here is a code to transform a column value:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(value = stringr::str_replace(value, '(^he following object)', '\\1'),
         value = stringr::str_replace(value, '(^Attaching package:)', '\\1'),
         value = stringr::str_replace(value, '(^package ‘ggplot2’)', '\\1'))
) %>%   
  group_by(ID, value)
```

the output is:

```
ID       value
1      he following object
2      Attaching package: 
3      package ‘ggplot2’
4      Warning messages:
```

As you see i use stringr::str_replace several times for one column. my actual data is much much larger (like millions of rows). this is just a subset example. so, how could i combine this three times using of this functioning one time? i want to use same functions and libraries(no radical change)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you should be able to find it useful to replace `str_replace` with `str_replace_all` in your code using a pipe operator `|` to avoid needing to call `str_replace` multiple times in different lines.

E.g.:

```
table_patterns <- table %>% 
mutate(value = str_replace_all(value, "(^he following object)|(^Attaching package:)|(^package ‘ggplot2’)", '\\1')) %>%   
group_by(ID, value)
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to do that with str_starts() function?

Comment: Based on the documentation, yes, it looks like that's essentially performing the same regex as what you're trying to do here. I was trying to give you a general pattern beyond just this specific use case.

Comment: could u please show how it would look like with str_starts() ?